# Read JSON file from ionic promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, rest, ionic-framework

I'm working on an ionic project, and trying to read a JSON file from local, through a promise sent from a sevice, and finally injected into a controller. However, I am getting the error **SyntaxError: Unexpected token J**, where **J** is always the first character from my JSON file.

Anyone have an idea?? Thanks very much!!!

I have a route in an **app.js**

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
  .state('home', {
     url: '/',
     templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
     controller: 'MainCtrl as vm',
     resolve: {
        weather: function(MyService) {
           return MyService.getData();
     }
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

My **services.js** is here

```
.factory('MyService', function($http) {

   var base_url = "http://localhost:8100/";

   function getData() {
       return $http.get(base_url+'data/pt_br/mydata.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
          .then(
             function(res) {
                return res;
             },
             function(err) {
                return err;
             }
          )
   }

   return { getData: getData() }
});
```

Here is my **controller**

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function(weather) {

   var vm = this;
   vm.weather = weather;
});
```

And, finally, my json file:

```
JSON_CALLBACK ({
    'Introduction': 'Welcome to my site!',
    'texts' : [
        'text1': 'hello',
        'text2': 'world'
    ]
});
```

Comment: I guess JSON needs double quotes and not single. Also `SyntaxError: Unexpected token J` means string is starting with `J`

Comment: I've already tried with double quotes, Rajesh, but doesn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem. I found out that my json file was sent like text-plain. I pass my json file within a json validator https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/, then, I realized the **ALL STRINGS** should be wrapped in double quotes, not only values. Thanks for @Rajesh for the clue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need top be using `JSONP` because when it comes back it actually has  the function name as the first part of the response.

The change you need in your code is:

```
 return $http.jsonp(base_url+'data/pt_br/mydata.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
```

Read about jsonp so you know what is going on [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).  Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saarmstrong/hYACX/8/) that shows you how to use jsonp.

If you checkout the networking call you will see Angular swaps out the JSON_CALLBACK with something it sets up so you might have trouble trying to mock it out.

```
angular.callbacks._1({"data": "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"});
```

Comment: Thank you Nix, but I would to solve this issue with a more natural way. I'm using a CORS browser extension to avoid cross-origin police problems. I realy fell that I am close the solution, Can you know any way to solve this with $http get? Or $resource?